# is matlab's xmlread using too much memory?

Tags: xml, dom, matlab

I am running into a memory problem when trying to read in large (not huge!) xml files. Estimating Java memory usage is tricky, but it seems that
`dom=xmlread('somefile.xml');`
takes way more memory than it ought to. I know how to set the default available Java memory in the preferences, but I am already up to 512MB and not even my full "resolution" xmls yet. And memory usage definitely does not scale well with file size.

If it will help I could provide a link to a ~5MB xml file that takes ~60MB of Java memory with xmlread.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,
-n

Comment: It is more a Java question then MATLAB one. MATLAB xmlread() function is just a wrapper around standard Java DOM xml import http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html (type `edit xmlread` in MATLAB command window). It is known to be very memory inefficient. There are many other Java xml parsers, also other methods, e.g. SAX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [XML IO Tools](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools) from the file exchange as an alternative way of reading your file.

Also take a look at the Mathworks doc on [Resolving "out of memory" errors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-49.html).

Comment: quoting the documentation:"function xml_read first calls MATLAB's xmlread function". I doubt that XML IO Tools will improve the SP's memory issues.